# Use Emacs to Edit Googleplus posts

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, emacs, edit

I would like to use emacs to edit googleplus posts. Is there a script that would launch emacs whenever I edit a post? I do not have good javascript skills but I am willing to try if I am pointed to the right direction. I use Chrome as my main browser but occassionaly use Firefox as a backup.

Comment: pentadactyl has bindings to launch external editors and I would love to tell you more, but this question is really off-topic ;)

Comment: Thanks @pmr I will Google it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of anything specific to Google Plus but here is what I use to edit forms in Emacs.

- in Chrome, I use the [**Edit with Emacs**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ljobjlafonikaiipfkggjbhkghgicgoh) plugin
- in Firefox, the [**It's all text**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) plugin will do what you want.

Both add a small *edit* button on each form that you can click to edit with Emacs (or any editor for *It's all text*).

Answer (score 0):

In firefox, I use keysnail https://github.com/mooz/keysnail/wiki with its HOK plugin installed.

So I have the emacs hotkeys and very useful 'follow hint' feature

Comment: This only works on linux I suppose, am I right? Keysnail looks to be a good solution too but I would prefer something that I can use on windows as well. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: works on all platoforms. I'm using it on Linux/Mac/Windows now.